# help is needed in audio streaming

Tags: php, audio

What are the available options for me to stream a Audio file, in a website build on PHP?
What is the minimum RAM to have in the server to reduce the buffer time

Comment: PHP is not really the right solution for this. A streaming server - there are affordable hosted solutions as well - would be much better and less resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

I use influxis for streaming. http://www.influxis.com/?gclid=CPO2u5r4qqsCFZF-5QodBmde9w.

If you just want to play mp3 files with a player let me know and Ill post a link to the player I use.

You do not need to worry about RAM playing a mp3 file through a flash player